# How do I put CSS inside a string?

Tags: html, css

I am saving an HTML file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
            #{my_str}
        </body>
        </html>
```

`my_str` fills in the contents of the HTML page.  Inside of `my_str` are list items that I want to indent. To do this I tried adding a CSS tag to the bottom to indent all `li` tags like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
            #{my_str}
        </body>
        </html>
li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Unfortunately, the output is displayed on the page instead of adding to the bottom as a padding for `li` items:

```
li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in `<style>` tags, just like normal.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `<style>` tag:

```
File.open("features/output/all_test_breakdown.html", "w") { |file| file.write(
      " <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
   <style>
    li {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
                #{my_str}
            </body>
            </html>
    " )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Here's how to write this more idiomatically. Starting with this rewrite:

```
my_str = 'foo'
File.open("my_output.html", "w") do |file|
  file.write(<<EOT)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
    #{my_str}
</body>
</html>
EOT
end
```

I'd refine it further using:

```
my_str = 'foo'
File.write("my_output.html", <<EOT)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
    #{my_str}
</body>
</html>
EOT
```

If sticking a "here-to" in the `write` method bugs you, you could do:

```
my_str = 'foo'
html = <<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
    #{my_str}
</body>
</html>
EOT

File.write("my_output.html", html)
```

Or:

```
my_str = 'foo'
html = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>'Previous Test Run Breakdown'</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Breakdown of results by structure</h1>
    #{my_str}
</body>
</html>
"

File.write("my_output.html", html)
```

In any case:

```
File.new("features/output/my_output.html", "w")
File.open("features/output/my_output.html", "w") { |file| file.write(
...
```

is code smell. You don't need to use `new` to create a file stub then `open` it followed by a [`ios.write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-write). Simply [`IO.write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-write) it.

If you're just learning Ruby, the difference between the two will seem hard to decipher, but the first is a writing to a file handle, AKA "ios" AKA "IO-stream". The second is a class method of "IO", AKA "IO.write", which handles the intermediate steps of opening the file, writing the content and closing it automatically.

Comment: You are always great! :) always enjoyed your answwer.